# How to make user interface for a HasTraits class using the Enthought Tool Suite

Tags: python, traits, enthought, traitsui

I have two class, it is child class of HasTraits.
this case:

```
  view =View(
    VGroup(
        HGroup(
            Label(u' '),
            Item(
                "bt_import", label=' '
            ),
            Item(
                "bt_export", label=' '
            ),
            show_left=False
        ),
        HGroup(
            Label(u' '),
            Item(
                "signalplot",
                editor=ComponentEditor(size=(600, 300)),
                show_label=False
            ),
            Label(u' '),
        ),
        HGroup(
            Label(u' '),
            Item(
                "spectrumplot",
                editor=ComponentEditor(size=(600, 300)),
                show_label=False
            ),
            Label(u' '),
        ),
   ),
    width=600,
    height=800,
    resizable=False,
    title=u"FFT 过滤"
)
```

In here, I will put two class. signalplot<-signal class and spectrumplot<-spectrum class
two class:

```
class Signal(HasTraits):
     view = View()
.......

class Spectrum(HasTraits):
       view = View()
.......
```

This case, How to make two class?
and How to put two class in interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you're looking for is this:

```
class MySignalSpectrumView(HasTraits):
    sig = Instance(Signal)
    spec = Instance(Spectrum)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mssv = MySignalSpectrumView()
    mssv.configure_traits(view=view)
```

That is, you are calling `edit_traits` or `configure_traits` on the model class and passing it the view you want to use.
Defining a `traits_view = View(...)` will provide the view used by default.
There are lots of good examples in the docs and the demos directory that ships with Traits, TraitsUI, and Chaco.

Comment: I tired it. But it is generated traits error. in words, mssv.configure_traits(view=view) is not excute. thanks

Comment: Make sure that `view`, `Signal`, and `Spectrum` are all defined in that file or explicit imported.You'll either have to post the error traceback to this question or figure it out by looking into the traceback yourself.